# How to change sleep button to lock session?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'd like to reprogram the physical sleep/power button on my laptop to go to the lock screen so I can quickly switch to another user.

Is there a way to either run a task on pressing the button, reprogram the button to perform a keypress, or reprogram the sleep command to lock the pc instead?

Comment: You can set it to another function, locking the system is unfortunately not one of them. This can be done from the Power Management settings screen.

Comment: Thanks, but I really need it to lock or switch users.  I'm hoping someone knows a registry hack or something to make it run a command

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using WIN+L? But what you want is simply not possible. Its a hardware button with limited software capabilities. Unless it is adjusted in Windows, this is not going to work.

Comment: @LPChip It's not just a hardware button though, as its behaviour can be changed in software (Windows) to either, sleep, hibernate or shut down or do nothing.   So it can in theory be repurposed in software with a windows setting.   The reason I want to use it is the button also doubles up as a fingerprint reader on my laptop - I have two accounts setup, a personal and work account and often switch between the two many times.  It would be very handy to press that button and then scan my fingerprint to log on as a different user all with one click

Comment: No, it IS a hardware button in the sense that when its pressed, a signal is sent to the BIOS which relays it to the OS, but it is hardcoded in the OS and handled on a deeper level so the button also works if no user is logged in, etc. Because of this, only predefined states can be configured.